# What is the difference in $('div') and $('div:parent')

Tags: jquery, selector

What is the difference in $('div') and $('div:parent'), They both returns the same result.

Comment: `div` selects all div elements. `div:parent` selects all `div` elements that have at least one child element or node. http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 1):

The **:parent Selector** page on jQuery says:

> Select all elements that have at least one child node (either an element or text).

So `$('div')` would select *all* divs and `$('div:parent')` would select *only those with children*.

Read more at http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Select all elements that have at least one child node (either an element or text). it is just reverse of empty.

```
<table border="1">
   <tr><td></td><td>Value 1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Value 2</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

the following code will fade non-empty td

```
$("td:parent" ).fadeTo( 1500, 0.3 );
```

while

```
$("td:empty" ).fadeTo( 1500, 0.3 );
```

will fade empty (no content) td

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery selector when you write $('div') its mean all div in relevant page but when you added $(div:parent) then first div of child div select.